# Convert string to timestamp

Tags: lua, type-conversion, datetime-format

How can I convert this string into a timestamp in Lua?

2017-02-04T15:12:02.866Z

I have browsed SO for examples and they all return nil, nil, nil...

For example, this does not work:

```
local pattern = "(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+)"
local timeToConvert = "2017-02-04T15:12:02.866Z"
local runyear, runmonth, runday, runhour, runminute, runseconds = timeToConvert:match(pattern)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are just missing a 'T' in the pattern:

`local pattern = "(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+)T(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)"`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how luatz's [`parse.rfc_3339`](https://daurnimator.github.io/luatz/#parse.rfc_3339) does it: https://github.com/daurnimator/luatz/blob/eabec5f434225aa68aa33565d8cf5055f287662e/luatz/parse.lua#L8